# how to assign auto incremented id names to buttons in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, mxml, auto-increment

i am amateur in flex, and started my final year project in flex to learn it, i am stuck in place where i have to create rows of drop down lists when the user pressed add more, eg: like the ones in mail attachments

i think i have found a way to generate rows, i am not even sure whether it is a correct way, may be there are easy ways..if so please let me know
this is how i generate the rows:

```
<mx:states>
    <mx:State name="newRow">
        <mx:AddChild relativeTo="{cityDropdown}">
            <s:DropDownList id="newbutton" creationComplete="hotelDropdown_creationCompleteHandler(event)" labelField="Name">
                <s:AsyncListView list="{getAllHotelResult.lastResult}"/>
            </s:DropDownList>
            </mx:AddChild>
    </mx:State>
</mx:states>
```

now when i generate more rows the dropdownlist ids will conflict, so i want to know a way to generate ids, i think i cant even call a function in there :(

please help...deadline is near :(

Answer (score 1):

It just happens that I created something very similar recently, but using ComboBoxes rather than DropDownList - where the user can click Add More and a new ComboBox will slide down on a new row (right click the demo on my site to View Source - link below).

Maybe you can get some inspiration from that.

To auto increment the id names, you going to have to do some AS3 coding. Each time a button is created, its name will become "whaterver" + i (with i as an int incrementing each time)

http://bbishop.org/blog/?p=448

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand about the state you used, but to do multi dynamic generated view, i choose to use "Event Bubbling" strategy and let the control without id.

wrap your controls into one component than make the event bubble from the component. than add listener on the parent of the control. thats all.

```
//in your custom control
dispatchEvent(new Event("myCustomEvent", true));

//in the parent control
parentComponent.addEventListener("myCustomEvent", myEventHandler);
```